# I want my text strike through extend on whitespace

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, strikethrough

I use `NSAttributeString` to set strike through on my text, I want it extend on `whitespace`.

I already set the correct range, but the strike through only cover the text characters. The strike through is ignore the whitespace unless I add some non-empty text before and after it.

How can I make the strike through extend on whitespace without extra text?

[image]

Comment: Please share your code you tried so far

Comment: You cannot do it directly because this is native behavior! you can do some trick as @Nirav D has suggested in his answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any solution but with your last option means adding first and last character as `.` with space you can try one thing. Either set the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` of that first and last character to your background color of label or set the `NSFontAttributeName` with `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1)`. So it will be goes like this. You haven't specify your answer language so i'm posting answer in latest Swift 3.

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.lbl.text!)
attributedText.addAttributes([NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: 2], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.lbl.text!.characters.count))
self.lbl.attributedText = attributedText
```

**Before using `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` & `NSFontAttributeName`**
[image]

Now you can use either `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` or `NSFontAttributeName` to hide first and last `dot(.)` character.

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.lbl.text!)
attributedText.addAttributes([NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: 2], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.lbl.text!.characters.count))
attributedText.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
attributedText.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], range: NSMakeRange(self.lbl.text!.characters.count - 1, 1))
//Or either Set NSFontAttributeName instead of NSForegroundColorAttributeName
//attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1)], range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
//attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1)], range: NSMakeRange(self.lbl.text!.characters.count - 1, 1))
self.lbl.attributedText = attributedText
```

**After using `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` or `NSFontAttributeName`**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have come across the same problem today, and neither existing answers gave me a solution I felt was as straightforward as it should be. After some research, I found a more concise solution using Unicode characters.

Padding each side of your text with one or more non-breaking Unicode space characters `(U+00A0)` extends the line as desired:

```
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(
    string: "\u{00A0}\(someText)\u{00A0}",
    attributes: [.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For people coming to this question who only want a horizontal line through whitespace, this is the way to do it (Swift 4):

```
let line = String(repeating: "\u{23AF}", count: 10)
```